# How do you access a model attribute (liste) in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I read a model 'List' from Spring model and setting up it into a jquery in loop? I'm using Thymeleaf as Template Engine.

**Spring-side: rdv.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/RdvListe", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String RdvListe(Model model) {

    List<Rdv> listRdv=rdvMetierImp.listRdv();

    model.addAttribute("listRdv",listRdv);

    return "RdvListe";
}
```

**Client-side: script.js**

```
$(function () {
    var events = [
        {
            title: 'Rdv with adam',
            start: '2017-06-09'
        }
    ];
});
```

**Result is like this:**

```
$(function () {
    $.each(listRdv, function (key, value) {
        var events = [
            {
                title: value.title,
                start: value.date'
            }
        ];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, you could use a converter from Java object to JSON. Such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Then your code can be following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(listRdv);
model.addAttribute("listRvd", jsonInString);
```

Then in your thymeleaf template, you can assign this JSON object as a javascript variable.

Although It is not the best practice you can try this out.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML page write the below script

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
var listRdv= [[${listRdv}]];
</script>
```

In script.js file use listRdv variable

```
var events=[];

$.each(listRdv, function(index,value){

  var event={
          title: value.title,
          start: value.date'
            };
  events.push(event);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find in the official Thymeleaf [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart):

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
...

var listRdv= [[${listRdv}]];

...
/*]]>*/
```

Comment: What is it that you dont want?

Comment: You van loop through it after you got it ín javascript